# How to repeat a piece of code a certain amount of times in Python

Tags: python, loops, repeat

I'm trying to write a piece of code about making a cup of tea (school homework).

Here is my code:

```
print("Making A Cup Of Tea")
a = input("How many for Tea")
print("there are", a, "People for tea")
b = input("Would you like Sugar? YES/NO")
if b == "YES":
    c = input("How many sugars?")
elif b == "NO":
    print ("Okay No sugar")
e = input("How Much Milk Would You Like? SMALL/MEDIUM/LARGE")
print("YOUR ORDER IS BEING PROCESSED PLEASE WAIT...")
if a == "1":
    print("There is", a, "Order with", c, "sugar(s), with", e, "amount of milk")
elif a >= "2":
    print("There is", a, "Orders with", c, "sugar(s), with", e, "amount of milk")
```

But instead of having to make the same order, how could I adapt it so that the amount of people having tea, in this case `a` would be printed at the bottom?

For example:

There are 3 people having tea, so I want the program to repeat 3 times and then print at the bottom every order individually.

Comment: Lookup the docs for 'for in' and 'range()'. f.e. 'for i in range(10):'

Comment: okay that has helped, but what i want it to do is the number of people having tea so if 3 people are having tea then i want it to repeat it an inputted amount of times.

Comment: range can handle integer variables you can simply use range(a)

Comment: Hi @MaxxB, please take a look to the answers below, I think that they respond to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help you:

```
print ("Making A Cup Of Tea")
num_orders = int(input("How many for Tea? "))
print ("there are", num_orders, "People for tea")
orders = []
for i in range(num_orders):
    b = input ("Person %i, Would you like Sugar? YES/NO " % (i + 1))
    sugar = None
    if b in ("YES", "Y", "y", "yes"):
        sugar = input("How many sugars? ")
    else:
        print ("Okay No sugar")

    milk = input("How Much Milk Would You Like? SMALL/MEDIUM/LARGE ")

    print ("Order is being processed, next order:\n")
    orders.append({'sugar': sugar, 'milk': milk })

print('The orders has been processed with these data:')
for i in range(num_orders):
    order = orders[i]
    print (' - Person', i + 1, 'wants tea', ('with %i' % int(order['sugar']) if order['sugar'] else 'without'), 'sugar and ', order['milk'], 'milk')
```

The previous code will generate an output similar to:

```
Making A Cup Of Tea
How many for Tea? 3
there are 3 People for tea
Person 1, Would you like Sugar? YES/NO y
How many sugars? 1
How Much Milk Would You Like? SMALL/MEDIUM/LARGE small
Order is being processed, next order:

Person 2, Would you like Sugar? YES/NO n
Okay No sugar
How Much Milk Would You Like? SMALL/MEDIUM/LARGE large
Order is being processed, next order:

Person 3, Would you like Sugar? YES/NO y
How many sugars? 2
How Much Milk Would You Like? SMALL/MEDIUM/LARGE small
Order is being processed, next order:

The orders has been processed with these data:
 - Person 1 wants tea with 1 sugar and small milk
 - Person 2 wants tea without sugar and large milk
 - Person 3 wants tea with 2 sugar and small milk
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for x in range(n):
    do_something()
```